# Javascript to detect if enhanced spell check is enabled in browser

Tags: javascript, security, spell-checking

Chrome and Edge have an option to spell check form contents as its typed in by the person completing the form.
Spell checks can be *off*, *on* or *enhanced*.
When *enhanced* is chosen the contents of the form are sent to Google or Microsoft for enhanced spelling and grammar checking leading to an issue labelled as spell-jacking.

If the content of the form is private or sensitive then sending the data to Google or Microsoft may lead to all sorts of issues.

I know there is a spellcheck attribute

```
spellcheck="false"
```

but this turns off spell checking.  Local spell checking is permitting and a required feature.  Enhanced Spell checking, where selected, should display a warning to the viewer and potentially stop the form from being edited.

Is there a way to run a javascript to detect what level of spell checking the browser viewing the page is running so that we can warn the end user about this issue?

Comment: Re: "spell-jacking," see [this article](https://www.otto-js.com/news/article/chrome-and-edge-enhanced-spellcheck-features-expose-pii-even-your-passwords) linked from [the MDN page for `spellcheck`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/spellcheck).

Comment: If the form field may have sensitive content, you need to turn off spellchecking on it. Even basic spellchecking *could* use network resources. Whoever told you you need to allow "basic spellchecking" in fields that may contain sensitive information needs to be educated.

Comment: Alternative is to disable browser spell checking then implement your own custom-built spell check (or one someone else wrote ofc):  [how to add spell check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940924/add-spell-check-to-my-website)

Comment: @freedomn-m - That's a smart idea. It has the downside that the user's personal dictionary additions won't be included, but better than nothing and better than leaking PII / sensitive data.

Comment: Related discussion on updating browsers to make this more available (goes on a bit) https://github.com/w3c/editing/issues/166